# 4 pole 3.5mm audio cable to a single pole compatibility

Tags: audio, microphone, plug

A very simple question.

I just want to understand how a 4 pole TRRS jack works. Say I have a 4 pole extension cable (male-female) that Id like to use with a mic on one end and the other end to connected to a pc (mic input).. Is a 4 pole jack compatible in this case ? or do I need modify it ?

Comment: Insufficient data: What 4-pole extension cable? What, to your understanding, is a 4-pole anything? "pole" would be a term typically applied to switches, or to frequency graphs, or analog filter designs, and so on. So some clarification might help the question. Voting to put on hold until question is improved.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh in context, 4 Pole = 4 conductor TRRS, instead of "Stereo" 3 conductor (L+R+Gnd) TRS.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh same as a "stereo" patch cable, but with four wires inside instead of 3. Like a mono patch cable has only two wires.

Comment: What do you mean "how does it work?" There are four copper lines through it and they conduct. One wire connects tip to tip, another ring1 to ring2, then ring2 to ring2 and sleeve to sleeve.  The sleeve is usually used as the ground for all combined return currents, and the wire may actually be a cable shield.  The tip and ring(s) carry unbalanced signals, like left and right audio, and microphone signal.

Comment: If you have a four conductor cable, you have to solder it in the correct way to a plug, or possibly two plugs, which match your PC's inputs, and attach the other end to your transducer devices in the correct way.

Comment: each of the answers below clarified how the plug works. thats exactly what i was after. I just wanted to know if I could use the 4 conductor TRRS cable to extend a mic cable which only has 2 contacts (TS) and also a speaker cable with 3 contacts (TRS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRRS is a 4 conductor cable + plug. It is used for different reasons, but normally involves a Left Audio, Right Audio, Ground, and Accessory/Mic/Video conductor. Wiring can vary, with Ground and the Accessory conductor being switched. It is an extension of the "Stereo" 3.5mm TRS Plug (L+R+Gnd), which itself is an extension of the "Mono" 3.5mm TS Plug (L+Gnd).

Some googling shows that you can get simple adaptor cables to use an iPhone headset with a pc mic in.

All it is is a physical adaptor. You would need to make sure that only the mic and ground pins are on the PC Mic In side, not the Left/Right audio out pins.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe a microphone input on a PC is [typically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports) a 3.5mm **TRS** jack (socket) with a pink surround. This is not a TRRS socket and may not be designed to work with TR or TRRS plugs.

Phones often use a 3.5mm **TRRS** jack but Nokia and Apple wire them up differently. I read that Apple's iDevice TRRS jack is specifically designed to also be able to accept a TRS plug.

However as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_and_video_interfaces_and_connectors#Audio_connectors) says *"A myriad of multi-conductor cable plug connectors and matching sockets are used for analog and digital audio connections."*

See also ["TRRS standards"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#TRRS_Standards) (sic)

Comment: Phones haven't used 2.5mm jacks in a while. Especially not Apple phones. They have always used a 3.5mm TRRS.

Comment: @Passerby: I sit corrected. Answer updated.